# Add condition to regex to match only ASCII characters

Tags: regex

I have this regex:

`/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)\S{7,127}.+$/` (at least one uppercase, one downcase, one digit, no space, len 8 to 128)

I want to add a new condition: only ASCII chars

Currently I'm trying with: `/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(^\p{ASCII})\S{7,128}.+$/`

Which works for (doesn't match): `"çko#1!RtsdsWs"`

But will match (I want to don't match because of `ç`): `"kço#1!RtsdsWs"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a positive lookahead to check for ASCII character before matching each non-space character.

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?:(?=\p{ASCII})\S){8,128}$
```

OR

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?:(?=[[:ascii:]])\S){8,128}$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xE6kU4/1)

Comment: Good. And if I don't want whitespaces?

Answer (score 0):

It is not well documented, but almost all POSIX regex implementations should depend on LC_CTYPE environment variable (which itself use to depend on LC_ALL or LANG env variables).

What POSIX say: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05

What is implemented in glibc: https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/posix/regcomp.c.html

What sed say: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Locale-Considerations.html#Multibyte-regexp-character-classes

What grep say: https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Character-Encoding

On the other hand the '[[:ascii:]]' charset don't even exist in many regex implementation. Then the most portable way is to set LC_CTYPE environment variable to "C" before computing your regexp. And then you may use your first regexp:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)\S{7,127}.+$/
```